# Using rename() which works but giving warning at the same time

Tags: php, function, rename

OK I'm confused. This code is showing me an error but at same time is doing what I actually needed.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./');
foreach ($dir as $filename) {
   if (mimes_content_type($filename) == 'txt') {
       rename($filename, './txt/'.$filename);
   }
}
```

> **Warning:** rename(txt,./txt/txt.txt): Invalid argument in ./www/session/test.php on line 78

Some advices what i did wrong ?

Comment: Invalid argument means your are passing a wrong argument to the function. But as per the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) your coding is correct. might be a issue in your php version. please try it in another version of php. when i try i haven't get into any issues. and also [mimes_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) is deprecated.

Comment: i'm using the last php version. I downloaded and installed it 1 week ago. Well what would you recommend me to use for mime types of the files in folder ?

Comment: I Prefer `finfo` to get the mime type of a file like below. `$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./');
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
foreach ($dir as $filename) {
 if (finfo_file($finfo, $filename)  == 'text/plain') {
  rename($filename, './txt/'.$filename);
 }
}
finfo_close($finfo);`